Where are the rig layers in blender 4.1?

I am currently using the Blender 4.1.
It seems like they removed or moved bone layers, does anyone know where it is now?

This is what it looks like in 4.1

The Blender latest release notes are your friend in situations like this.

It's now a new system called Bone Collections:

